# Linq OrderByDescending after that ThenByDescending in C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have list of integer and I am trying to sort this based on first  in descending order and after that I want to sort with in two list based on even and odds but still in descending order  like this

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var numbers = new List<int>() { 3, 7, 1, 5, 4, 6, 2 };
        var sortedDescendingNumbers = numbers.OrderByDescending(x => x);
        var sortedNumbers = sortedDescendingNumbers.ThenByDescending(x => x % 2 == 0);

        foreach (var num in sortedNumbers)
        {
            Console.Write(num + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

but this one print the result as `7 6 5 4 3 2 1`  and I am expecting output like `7 5 3 1 6 4 2`

Answer (score 1):

Your first block of numbers should be the odd ones, so you have to order by divisibility by 2 first and then by descending value.

```
var sortedOddEvenNumbers = numbers.OrderBy(x => x % 2 == 0);
var sortedNumbers = sortedOddEvenNumbers.ThenByDescending(x => x);
```

Comment: `OrderBy` instead of `OrderByDescending`

Comment: Can you point out why if I use this line modulus by 2  as second line then nothing happen ?

Comment: @rahularyansharma If you sort by decending first, you create 7 buckets with one item each: [[7],[6],[5],[4],[3],[2],[1]]. Then you sort each bucket by even-ness which does nothing as there is only one element in each bucket.
If you sort by even-ness first, you create 2 buckets: [[3,7,1,5],[4,6,2]]. After that you sort each bucket by decreasing value and get [[7,5,3,1],[6,4,2]].